# how to include an interface in java class

Tags: java

I want to include an interface `Printable` to this class but it is showing an error.

```
error:Class file collision: A resource exists with a different case:     
'/example01/bin/com/example/test/test.class'.
```

This is my code

```
package com.example.test;

import com.example.test.Printable;

class A implements Printable {
    public void a() {
        System.out.println("a method");
    }

    @Override
    public void b() {

    }

}

abstract class B implements Printable {
    public void b() {
        System.out.println("b method");
    }

}

class Call {
    void invoke(Printable p) {// upcasting
        if (p instanceof A) {
            A a = (A) p;// Downcasting
            a.a();
        }
        if (p instanceof B) {
            B b = (B) p;// Downcasting
            b.b();
        }

    }
}// end of Call class

class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Printable p = new A();
        Call c = new Call();
        c.invoke(p);
    }
}
```

This is my Printable interface class code

```
public interface Printable {

    public void a ();
    public void b();
}
```

So how can i import the interface Printable to this class any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `but it is showing an error` What error?

Comment: `but it is showing an error` - well ... **which** error?

Comment: error:Class file collision: A resource exists with a different case: '/example01/bin/com/example/test/test.class'.

Comment: Your class and the interface are in same package. You need not import that.

Comment: Rebuild it, make sure all your classes/resources don't clash on name etc.

Comment: Here is the rule, at most 1 public(package local is also accepted) class per file. File name should match with class name inside file(case sensitive)

Comment: I do not get any errors with your code. There must be something else - from your comment, I assume that you have a `Test.java` and a bogus `test.class` file - remove the latter one and recompile

Comment: You most likely have in some other java file in the same package another class named `test`. Choose another name for your class, f.i. `Test2`.

Comment: @A4L-yeah i had one more class named test i deleted it and now its working fine thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is my approach to embed a interface to a class:

```
public class NestedClassInterface {

/**
 * Nested interface
 * @author Markus
 */
public interface Printable {
    public void a();
}

/**
 * MAIN
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Printable t = new MyTest();
    t.a();
}

/**
 * Static class (otherwise the compiler cannot find it)
 * @author Markus
 *
 */
public static class MyTest
implements Printable {
    public void a() {
        System.out.println("NestedClassInterface.MyTest.a()");
    }
}
```

}

## Notes

- As [Admit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2772755/admit) highlights: There is only one (1) class allowed within a file. Naming should be consistent.
- `java.util.Map` uses the same approach to have its entries defined `Map.Entry`: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Map.java.html

Keep us posted on your progress.